# JUNG layout for left-to-right placement of nodes

Tags: jung, jung2

Is there an optimal layout in JUNG for left-to-right placement of nodes in the graph? I'm looking for something that would model a data lineage and need to represent this somewhat linearly (left to right).

Comment: I'm not sure how you mean to define "optimal" or "somewhat linearly".  You're more likely to get a useful answer if you can define your problem more precisely.

Comment: I'm looking for a layout that is not centered around a focal point, but places the nodes from left to right, somewhat like a rotated tree

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your graph is a tree, then you can use the `TreeLayout` and do some post-processing to rotate it to have the root on the left instead of the top (see the [L2RTreeLayoutDemo](https://github.com/jrtom/jung/blob/jung-2.1.1/jung-samples/src/main/java/edu/uci/ics/jung/samples/L2RTreeLayoutDemo.java) for an example of how to do this).

If your graph is only sort of tree-shaped, then you may want to extract a tree from your graph first (see [MinimumSpanningTreeDemo](https://github.com/jrtom/jung/blob/jung-2.1.1/jung-samples/src/main/java/edu/uci/ics/jung/samples/MinimumSpanningTreeDemo.java) for one way to do this automatically) and then follow the procedure above.

If neither of those works for you (for example, this won't work if your graph has multiple "roots"), then you will probably need to create your own layout, perhaps based on `TreeLayout`.